# Making a coinflip in php (Provably fair)

Tags: php, html, css

so I'm trying to create website with a coinflip system (Its just a small project I'm doing in my free time) but I don't really know where to begin. I need to make it in php (so its in the backend) and I need it to be provably fair (so I can prove that it is legit). What I've found out is that I need to use something like sh256 but I also heard that its pretty out dated and can be easily cracked. Also if it matters it's a site with a steam login system so I plan on being able to join 1v1's with others steam users not just a person sitting besides me or something (not just 1 button is what I mean hehe).

EDIT: I have googled it and tried asking people I know and etc if they knew anything but nothing was any good.

Thanks in advance

-Eiríkur

Comment: you need to show the code you have written or at least an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Comment: And for what it's worth, SHA256 is perfectly secure... at least with current computational power :)

Comment: _create website with a coinflip system_ You mean a 50/50 chance game?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Maybe I'm misunderstanding, I'm not really sure why you would need to use SHA256 on a coin flip php script.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I wasn't asking for a free coding service, sorry if it looked like that. What I was trying to say is that I don't know where to begin and was wondering if anyone could tell me something like "you need to use this and this and google this" don't expected anyone to make it for me.

Comment: I just did.  random between 0 and 1 and then if 0 heads if 1 tails.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I'm guessing it would be tied in to a database that powers a leaderboard of some kind. It could also be crazy encryption that stores one hash for heads and one hash for tails ;)

Comment: Okay thanks :) good to know (I'm only on my first year in school learning web development and programming).

Comment: @Grumpy to make the coin secure obviously! With SHA256 nobody can steal the coin

Comment: @EiríkurÓliEyþórsson You can literally get a coin toss result with this single line of code: `$result = array("heads", "tails")[random_int(0,1)];`. This will give you heads or tails randomly. The way it works is, it generates a random 0 or 1 and uses that to select the array element and assign it to the `$result` variable.

Comment: Then run it 100,00 times (or whatever)  and divide count of heads and tails by 100,000 for a percentage that should be around 50%.  That will show that it is "fair" or at least statistically accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. To answer a few of yours like @ObsidianAge as far as my knowledge goes (not so far) I need a hash and secret and all that to show that the coinflip wasn't rigged (they need to match I saw online). 
 And GrumpyCrouton Thanks for that I will check it out! :) It's a good start :)

Comment: @EiríkurÓliEyþórsson My answer is actually cryptographically secure, so you don't need to worry about a hash or secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple way to get a random coin toss result:

```
$result = array("heads", "tails")[random_int(0,1)];
```

First, we make an array, which will be our choices. `array("heads, "tails")` means we will always get one of those 2 results. Next, in the same line, we can select a single element to actually assign to the `$result` variable from the array we made previously. We can use `random_int(min, max)` to generate that number.

> Note: `random_int()` generates cryptographic random integers that are
>   suitable for use where unbiased results are critical, such as when
>   shuffling a deck of cards for a poker game.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php

As a bonus, you could add more elements to this array, and then just increase the `max` value in `random_int()`, and it will work. You could make this more dynamic as-well by doing it like this:

```
$choices = ["heads", "tails", "Coin flew off the table"];
$result = $choices[random_int(0, count($choices)-1];
```

With the above code, you can have as many choices as you'd like!

---

**Testing**

I ran this code 50,000 times, and these were my results.

```
Array
(
    [heads] => 24923
    [tails] => 25077
)
```

And I ran this code 100,000 times, these were my results:

```
Array
(
    [tails] => 49960
    [heads] => 50040
)
```

You can play around with this here, to check out results:

https://eval.in/894945

Comment: `count($choices) - 1` or start array at 1.

Comment: Thank you :) this is pretty much what I needed I guess I was just making it more complicated ;P

Comment: @EiríkurÓliEyþórsson I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above might be the best for most of the scenarios.

In commercial usage, you might want to make sure that the results can be recalculated to prove fairness.

In the following code, you need to calculate a seed for the server. Besides, you also might want to create a public seed that users can see. Those can be anything but I do recommend using some kind of a [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). Each time you get a new result just increase the round, it will generate a new truly random result.

```
$server_seed = "96f3ea4d221ca1b2048cc3b3b844e479f2bd9c80a870628072ee98fd1aa83cd0";
$public_seed = "460679512935";

for($round = 0;$round < 10;$round++) {
    $hash = hash('sha256', $server_seed . "-" . $public_seed . "-" . $round);
    if (hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) % 2) {
        echo 'heads', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
         echo 'tails', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This code will loop through 10 times using [for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), each time generating a new result. In the code, we assign a SHA256 hash to the `$hash` variable. Then we can calculate the decimal value from the `$hash` using PHP inbuilt function [hexdec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php). We take the remainder from the decimal value and give the result based on it whether it's 0 or not.

> NOTE You can play around with the values. Changing the [substring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to `substr($hash, 0, 14)` will get you a different way of generation to the results. Keep in mind that this will not change the final results in any way.

Average results of 1 000 000 runs were the following:

```
Heads: 50.12%
Tails: 49.88%
```

You can experiment with the code above at [here](http://tpcg.io/FKsUFUYg).